# Idiom for the phrase "getting a good result from a bad situation or with a bad condition"?

Tags: idioms

Is there an idiom which expresses the idea of "getting a good result from a bad situation or with a bad condition"?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you pulled it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well-worn way to put this is: [When life gives you lemons, make lemonade.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_life_gives_you_lemons%2C_make_lemonade)

Or, to match your question: Making lemonade when life has given you lemons.

It may not be quite right for you, since it is often used as a prod towards positive thinking, rather than a statement of results.

Answer (score 1):

"Flipping the script"

flip the script (third-person singular simple present flips the script, present participle flipping the script, simple past and past participle flipped the script)

(slang) To reverse a situation, especially by doing something unexpected.

source: 
https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/flip_the_script

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **to make the best of a bad situation**

> To deal with and create the best possible outcome of a bad, unfortunate, or unpleasant situation or set of circumstances

From [the Farlex Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+the+best+of+a+bad+situation)

The cliché **happy ending** also could work as an alternative.

 It originally was used to describe the common plotline of novels in which everything turned out well for the protagonist after a bad situation, but it is used now as an idiom to mean 'it all turned out well'.